# Creating vector of index of strings in column

Tags: r

i want to find the the string in dataframe and created the vector of rownumber.

lets say i want to find the c("call","boat") in dataframe and create a vector of it

for eg: (2,6)

```
library(expss)
data <- data.frame(
  Code = c("Tmed", "call", "mnag","kling","Card","boat","call"),
  sector = c(3, 3, 1,3,4,1,3),
  col1 = c(12, 15, 22,12,21,43,22),
  col2 = c(33, NA, 41,32,21,42,25),
  col3 = c(1, 1, 0,0,1,0,1),
  col4 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  col5 = c(1, 2, 1,1,2,1,2)
)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get what output you expect and what type of code/query you would like to launch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `which` command along with `%in%`, which will give the indices:

```
which(data$Code %in% c("call","boat"))
```

Output:

```
# [1] 2 6 7
```

Note that here 7 appears (in contrast to your question indicating `c(2, 6)`) because "call" is in both the 2nd and 7th positions. If this isn't correct please further clarify and I'll be happy to tweak.

If you want to find the row index of a particular string and replace all values in the row with 0, per your comment:

```
data[which(data$Code %in% c("call","boat")), ] <- 0
```

Output:

```
#    Code sector col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
# 1  Tmed      3   12   33    1   NA    1
# 2     0      0    0    0    0    0    0
# 3  mnag      1   22   41    0   NA    1
# 4 kling      3   12   32    0   NA    1
# 5  Card      4   21   21    1   NA    2
# 6     0      0    0    0    0    0    0
# 7     0      0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: actually the objectve is to find the row index of particular strings and the then replace all values in those row with 0

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect exactly what you want